# Carrierwave converts but image_tag call is to old name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

an uploader does the proper handling

```
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
    process :convert => 'jpg'
    def filename
      super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.jpg' 
    end
  end
```

in the store directory the uploaded file and its thumbnail are there. And the thumbnail is converted to jpg.

However the show view

```
<%= image_tag @docimage.production_file_url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

is rendering the path to the original name

```
<img alt="Thumb_30x30_2mb" src="/uploads/docimage/yadayadayada/thumb_30x30_2mb.tif" />
```

I'm missing something here for handling the new extension.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was expecting an existing method to handle the case.  But given the brevity of the solution, that was wildly mistaken.

```
def edited_thumb
  start_path = self.production_file_url(:thumb) 
  edited_thumb  = start_path.sub(/[^.]+\z/,"jpg")
end
```

then, in the view

```
<%= image_tag @model.edited_thumb %>
```